# https for static, rest maps?

Tags: https, here-api

I'm displaying a map on a web page. The entire site uses https. Browsers complain when you have non-https content displayed on an https page.

Is there a way to get an https url for REST here map images?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the URL directly using https (outside of the rest of your markup). If it works then the domain you are accessing supports https.

If that is the case, then in your markup do not reference the URL using "http" or "https" specifically, instead begin at just the forward slashes and don't specify a protocol. Then when your page is rendered, any url's beginning with "//" will automatically use the protocol used to access your page. So you won't need to worry about switching back and forth.

If the URL you are trying to access doesn't support https then you may be out of luck.

Example:
Don't use: src="http://www.mydomain.com/etc/etc" or src="https://www.mydomain.com/etc/etc"
Instead use: src="//www.mydomain.com/etc/etc"

Comment: I should have been more specific. The url is the nokia maps url. I am displaying a nokia here map on a web page, and that map is generated by nokia here rest api. I tried using https to access the nokia here rest api but it appeared to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an alternative **Enterprise** URL available to get the [Map Image API](http://developer.here.com/map_image) to return responses via HTTPS. However, this alternative is not part of the **Basic** free public API.

Instead of using the service at  `http://m.nok.it/`, you'll need to access the service at `https://maps.nlp.nokia.com/mia/1.6/mapview` instead (with your own [app_id and token](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token) of course.)

The same HTTP/HTTPS distinction occurs with the map tiles loaded the **Basic** and **Enterprise**  versions of the [Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript_api)

To upgrade to the Enterprise API - to obtain it you will need to click on the button to ***Request a custom package*** with more features at the bottom of the [plans](http://developer.here.com/plans) page

Answer (score 0):

Use [the Enterprise Javascript API](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics/overview.html) and set [secureConnection](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics_api_nlp/nokia.Settings.html#topic-apiref__Settings-secureConnection-static-property) to "force":

```
nokia.Settings.set("secureConnection", "force");
```